# HTML how to use position:absolute; without overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to use

```
#DivId{
    positon:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
 }
```

without overlapping other divs.

I am developing a design for a website that has to work over multiple pages, and I find the only way to get a div to have the width of the full screen is with:

```
position:absolute;
left:0px;
width:100%;
```

(instead of the

```
position:relative;
```

where it does not overlap but indents the div and when you use width:100%; it has a small margin on each side)

is there any way to do this or, alternatively, have a div stick to the bottom of a webpage (under a div that has position:absolute;) ?

Comment: No. Also, divs take up the full width by default (because they're block-level elements). Fix that problem instead of using absolute positioning.

Comment: What do you need it? For background?

Comment: maybe you can fix by setting in css *{margin:0;} to delete small margin on position relative.

Comment: Can you provide some code that reproduces your issue? As mentioned by isherwood, `div`s are block-level elements, and they will fill up to 100% of the width of it's container unless stated otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what you need to solve all of this is

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Now I know this I will go through all my code and optimize it! Thank You!

Comment: Google 'CSS reset' for some shortcuts. Twitter Bootstrap and other libraries do it for you, also.